# How can you control vibrotactile feedback with Rec Room circuits?

Tags: rec-room

Motion-tracked controllers for VR offer vibrotactile (haptic) feedback, e.g. when your hand collides with a physical maker pen object. How can you control the vibrotactile feedback with circuits?

I implemented one approach (for light switches) which consists of a physical maker pen object that is clamped with a gizmo. The gizmo releases it for a single tick when it gets an ("enter") signal from a trigger volume that is at the same location as the clamped physical maker pen object. This creates a nice short vibrotactile feedback. The disadvantage is that the physical maker pen object briefly moves out of position. For non-authority players the situation is even worse because they can apparently miss the reclamp and the object is then out of position until they touch it. Are there any alternatives to control vibrotactile feedback with circuits?

Answer (score 1):

The game gives us several elements that provide virbrofeedback under different circumstances:

- Bounce Pads provide vibrofeedback when the body collides with them.
- Impulse Volumes provide vibrofeedback when the body enters them.
- Setting the health player stat set to 0 vibrates both controllers for a short time.
- Picking up or dropping objects vibrates the corresponding controller.
- Touching physical objects provides feedback on the corresponding controller.
- Firing a weapon provides vibrofeedback in the corresponding controller.
- Hitting objects or players with a sword also provides vibrofeedback.

None of these really provide a better alternative to the usecase you used as an example, but these are all the ways that we have that give players. If you come up with more, add them to this list.